# MySQL overheads, is my query wrong or should I Optimise the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have a table setup like below.

```
Table comment_flags
    user_id
    comment_id
```

I allow users to flag a comment and then give them the option to unflag it, because they may have made a mistake.

The problem is that when they unflag a comment, after I delete the record , the `comment_flags` table get roughly 30-40bytes of overhead, even after only unflagging 5 comments.

Heres basically whats going on:-

A user flags a comment, so I insert `user_id` and `comment_id` into `comment_flags` table, then the user unflags the comment and I delete from the  `comment_flags` table by the `user_id` and `comment_id`.

I am not sure that it's my SQL thats causing the problem though, I think it's just the `DELETE` statement in general.

I could optimise the table after every `DELETE` statement to clean up the table.

Is this seen as a good idea? How does everyone else deal with this?

My sql is very basic.

```
INSERT INTO comment_flags VALUE('$user_id', '$comment_id')
DELETE FROM comment_flags WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND comment_id = '$comment_id'
```

Comment: Where are you getting this value from?

Comment: By Truncating then Optimising the table. After this I play with the code I have and I find that after about 5 'Unflags', I get about 30-40bytes of overhead as shown in phpMyAdmin

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634257/innodb-does-the-space-occupied-by-deleted-rows-get-re-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could optimise the table after every DELETE statement to clean up the table. Is this seen as a good idea?

For 30-40 bytes? No.

> How does everyone else deal with this?

By not bothering. The space [should be re-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634257/does-the-space-occupied-by-deleted-rows-get-re-used) for any subsequent `INSERT`s, and this is a *good* thing.

Comment: @SeanHJenkins Maybe not great, but correct. You'd probably want to `OPTIMIZE` the table after a lot of `DELETE`/`INSERT` happened.

Comment: Because I'd rather find a way to deal with the overheads than to 'not bother'. Otherwise it could have huge implications in the future.

Comment: At what point would a overhead become a problem? 1kb? 2kb? 500kb?

Comment: @SeanHJenkins: If you've already decided to ignore everybody's experienced advice, then why ask in the first place? It doesn't make my answer "not great" just because you don't like it. Your use of the term "overheads" is completely inaccurate anyway. Just let the DBMS do its job and quit worrying about a handful of bytes that you may not be filling with data for a few minutes.

Comment: I'm not ignoring it. I just believe that answering my question with 'dont bother' is not really a helpful answer.

Comment: @SeanHJenkins: I'm sorry you feel that way. It precisely and correctly answers the question. If I changed "by not bothering" to "people _don't_ 'deal with this'" (which means the exact same thing), would you be happier?

Comment: No, no. Simple mis-understanding. I've read through the link you left. Thanks