# How to free up space in a MySQL Amazon RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We are using an Amazon RDS instance and it ran out of free storage space. Looking into the issue we dropped a no-longer required table. Amazon's monitoring tool showed that 1Gb of space was now available.

Further investigation showed that another table had 7 million entries, so we removed 5 million of them (using a simple delete command). However now the Free Storage Space has dropped to almost 1/2 Gb. We are dangerously close to running out of space again.

I (naively) assumed that deleting entries from a table would reclaim space. Why is this not the case? Do I need to perform some form of manual cleanup operation? Why did performing the delete cause nearly 1/2 Gb of free space to be used (looking at the table the size was 2677Mb before the delete and is now 2961Mb!)

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: MySQL will keep the space reserved after deletion, but you can insert new rows in that space. Also, deletes will be logged, which may cause the that extra space to be used. For generic info about deleting rows see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634257/does-the-space-occupied-by-deleted-rows-get-re-used). For more info about log files and such on AWS, see [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may have unused indexes in your database which maybe taking up space. Percona makes tools and patches for MySQL to collect index usage data.

Check these links:

- [User statistics(index statistics](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/user_stats.html?id=percona-server%3Afeatures%3Auserstatv2)
- [pt-index usage](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-index-usage.html)

You can also have a look at these:

- [New table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage table in performance_schema in MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-waits-summary-tables.html)
- [New INDEX_STATISTICS table in the information_schema](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/patches%3Auserstatv2)

I'll recommend to use performance schema provided you use MySQL version 5.6 or higher. Also you can have look at [MONyog- Mysql Monitoring tool](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog). It include tools to monitor different performance metrics of the MySQL server, there's a disk info feature in it which might help you in this issue.